# VBA macro - Specifying new worksheet for data generated

Tags: excel, vba

At the moment I have a piece of code that can take start and end dates, and list all the dates in that date range.  This allows me to take the following table and split it down to individual dates.

```
|Name            | StartDate  | EndDate
|Bob The builder | 20/05/2015 | 24/05/2015 
|Tiny Tim        | 08/06/2015 | 09/06/2015
|Dolly Parton    | 06/08/2015 | 08/08/2015
```

However at the moment it dumps the created data directly below the existing table like this:

```
|Name            | StartDate  | EndDate
|Bob The builder | 20/05/2015 | 24/05/2015 
|Tiny Tim        | 08/06/2015 | 09/06/2015
|Dolly Parton    | 06/08/2015 | 08/08/2015
|Bob The builder | 20/05/2015 | 
|Bob The builder | 21/05/2015 |
|Bob The builder | 22/05/2015 | 
|Bob The builder | 23/05/2015 | 
|Bob The builder | 24/05/2015 | 
|Tiny Tim        | 08/06/2015 | 
|Tiny Tim        | 09/06/2015 | 
|Dolly Parton    | 06/08/2015 | 
|Dolly Parton    | 07/08/2015 |
|Dolly Parton    | 08/08/2015 |
```

I've tried several ways of trying to get it to locate it on a new sheet and each time I muck about with the code it fails.  Please also note copying generated data won't work, as each time I run this macro the original table will have a different number of rows.  This is the code I've been using:

```
Sub SeparateDateRange()

Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim nCol As Integer


Set Ws = ActiveSheet

nCol = 1 

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, nCol + 2).End(xlUp).Row - 1 Step 1 

    For j = 0 To Ws.Cells(i + 1, nCol + 2).Value - Ws.Cells(i + 1, nCol + 1).Value Step 1 

  With Ws.Cells(Ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1)
    For k = 0 To nCol - 1 Step 1
        .Offset(0, k).Value = Ws.Cells(i + 1, k + 1).Value
    Next k

    .Offset(0, nCol).Value = DateSerial(Year(Ws.Cells(i + 1, nCol + 1).Value), Month(Ws.Cells(i + 1, nCol + 1).Value), Day(Ws.Cells(i + 1, nCol + 1).Value) + j)
    End With

    Next j
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue your are experiencing comes from the fact that you are putting the generated values at an offset of `Ws` which you have defined as the active sheet `Set Ws = ActiveSheet`

This is reflected here:

```
With Ws.Cells(Ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1)
For k = 0 To nCol - 1 Step 1
    .Offset(0, k).Value = Ws.Cells(i + 1, k + 1).Value
Next k

    .Offset(0, nCol).Value = DateSerial(Year(Ws.Cells(i + 1, nCol + 1).Value), Month(Ws.Cells(i + 1, nCol + 1).Value), Day(Ws.Cells(i + 1, nCol + 1).Value) + j)
End With
```

Instead of using the active sheet, define a new sheet to insert the values to and reference it in your `With` for example:

```
Dim newWS as worksheet
Set newWS = Sheets("SheetName")

With newWS.Cells(newWS.Cells(newWS.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1)
```

This should put you on the right track.

Comment: I agree that this answer should point the OP in the right direction. However, `Rows.Count` refers to the ActiveSheet rather than `newWS`. This will not cause problems per se since all sheets have the same number of rows, but it is sloppy. `Rows.Count` should be preceded by `newWS.`.

Comment: Good catch Rachel Hettinger.  I have edited to reflect.